# How to use MAC address as primary key? (sqlite android)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How to use MAC address as primary key for my sqlite database: I can easily populate the database, and select *.

The problem is that I defined the MAC address to be CHAR(17) in order to get all characters and the collins

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_DEVICE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DEVICE + "("
        + COLUMN_DEVICE_MAC + " CHAR(17) PRIMARY KEY, "
        + COLUMN_DEVICE_LAST_TIME_DETECTION + " NUMERIC, "
        + COLUMN_DEVICE_LAST_TIME_RANGE + " REAL, "
        + COLUMN_DEVICE_DETECTION_FREQUENCY + " INTEGER, "
        + COLUMN_DEVICE_CUMULATIVE_DETECTION_DURATION + " REAL, "
        + COLUMN_DEVICE_PHONE_NUMBER + " VARCHAR(50), "
        + COLUMN_DEVICE_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME + " TEXT "
        +");";
```

But, then when fetching a row based on the primary key, I am having an issue since i am passing the MAC from the MAIN activity as string and also i am confusing how to use the quotations:

```
public Cursor getDatabyMAC(String MAC)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_DEVICE+" where _Did =? ",new String[]{MAC});
    return result;
}
```

or

```
public Cursor getDatabyMAC(String MAC)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_DEVICE+" where _Did = '"+device_ID+"'",null);
    return result;
}
```

Neither works by the way.

(Below is the main call)

```
public void onbtnclick2(View view) {

    Cursor result2 = myDb.getDatabyMAC("01:53:45:67:87:AE");
    txt_ReadSpecific.setText(result2.getCount());



}
```

Comment: Did you try to maybe call a `String#toUpperCase()` before calling the query? I mean, perhaps you're storing in upper case, and querying in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `COLLATE NOCASE` on the end of your query, maybe it's a problem with case sensitivity and that will make it search for the `String` regardless of being lower or upper case.

E.g.: `"select * from "+TABLE_DEVICE+" where _Did = '"+device_ID+"' COLLATE NOCASE"`

Answer (score -1):

here it is:

```
select hex(mac_addr) from table_Name;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table_Name (mac_addr) VALUES (x'0123456789AB');
```

for making mac_addr as primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE table_Name
```

`ADD PRIMARY KEY (mac_addr)`

Comment: applying hex(mac_addr) didnt work: 

Check output: 

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "0153456787ae" (code 1): , while compiling: select hex(0153456787ae) from device

Query: 
select hex(0153456787ae) from "+TABLE_DEVICE